# How to handle being asked to come back to a company previously worked at

Tags: management, hiring-process, work-experience

I was recently called by my former boss from a company that I previously worked at several years ago, and the short version is that they want to hire me back. While I left on good terms, I did not particularly enjoy the corporate culture or mentality (my team and coworkers were excellent, but many things were beyond their control). I am currently employed at another company (which I enjoy more right now, otherwise this wouldn't be much of a problem). How should I best explain to them that I don't want to go back at this time, without burning any bridges. Note that during my exit interview, I avoided mentioning anything that was completely beyond their control.

P.S. - I am not under any sort of non-compete agreement right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tell them that you are grateful for the opportunity, but that you are currently happy where you are and are not looking for other opportunities. Handle it the same way as if a recruiter contacted you for a job. Tell them you will keep in touch, and actually do so. Because honestly...you could be laid off tomorrow and will need to cross that bridge.

Answer (score 4):

> How should I best explain to them that I don't want to go back at this
>   time, without burning any bridges.

Nothing complex or unusual here.

Say something like "Thank you so much for the consideration, and I'm really flattered. But right now I'm happy with the job I have."

It's honest, and it won't burn any bridges.